# MySql renumbering rows results NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a problem with renumbering query:

```
SET @i = 0;
UPDATE jos_menu SET
    ordering = (@i := @i + 1)
    ORDER BY ordering ASC;
```

I first run the `SET @i = 0` query in phpmyadmin, then the UPDATE query, but it generates NULL values for every field.

What could be wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: Strange, as it works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a colon:

```
SET @i := 0;
```

The correct operator for user defined variables is `:=` not `=`.

Comment: Thanks for very fast response! I fixed the colon, but now i have second problem. Query shows that "0 rows affected". Why doesn't it update the column?

Comment: Unlike most other databases, with mysql the "number of rows affected" does not include updates where the value didn't change. You would get zero rows affected if you ran this update *again*.

Comment: Now i changed ORDER BY field and it generates all NULL values. I have really now idea what else to try :(

Comment: Create an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) for your schema and data and post the link here.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I exported my table to sql file and copied the table create part to left window. To right window i added my update query, but i get error message: DDL and DML statements are not allowed in the query panel for MySQL; only SELECT statements are allowed. Put DDL and DML in the schema panel.

Comment: ...it seems that it doesn't allow UPDATE query at all?!

Comment: SQL part only allows select. Put the update in with the schema at the end. put a simple select in the SQL part to show the update worked. (btw, if you read my comment, I didn't ask you to put the update in, I only asked for schema and data, for this very reason - it can be confusing, but have a go anyway)